# How do I stop a loop of fscanf at the end of a line?

Tags: arrays, c, file, linked-list

I have a file to read full of numbers and spaces between the numbers. I've initialized an array of linked lists and one line would correspond to one index of the array and one number corresponds to one node in the list.

I want to `fscanf` each line to scan each number and put it in the list but I want it to stop at the end of the line so that I can loop it so the next line would go to the next index of the array. I thought about using `fgetc` but some of the numbers are more than 1 digit and I think it would be harder if I used that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    do {
        node *new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        fscanf(fp, "%i", &new->data);
        new->next = NULL;
        new->prev = NULL;
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = new;
        } else {
            operand *temp = *head;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp->next == NULL) {
                new->prev = temp;
                temp->next = new;
            }
        }
    } while (new->data != '\n');
```

I don't know what to put in the while loop for it to stop at the end of the line and for my for loop to update to the new index. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: It seems like you want `break;` - I believe the keyword is the same in C.

Comment: So what you want to do, is to read whitespace-separated integers, and be notified when you reach the end of a line? All the linked-list stuff (which makes up the majority or the code) is irrelevant to the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure `fscanf()` does not consume the white space after the number, including the newline, you should remove the space at the end of the format string:

```
fscanf(fp, "%i", &new->data);
```

To stop the inner loop at the newline, change the code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int c;
    int data;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%i", &data) == 1) {
        node *new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(*new));
        new->data = data;
        new->next = NULL;
        new->prev = NULL;
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = new;
        } else {
            node *temp = *head;
            while (temp->next != NULL) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            new->prev = temp;
            temp->next = new;
        }
        // ignore trailing whitespace
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) == ' ' || c == '\t')
            continue;
        // detect end of line
        if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
            break;
        ungetc(c, fp);
    }
    ...
}
```